# Can I stay in UK after finishing my short English language courses?

Tags: visas, uk, london

I'm from Russia. 
I have student-visitor visa for 6 months of staying in UK. 
The length of my English language courses is 2 weeks.

Question: 
Can I stay in UK after finishing courses (up to my visa expire date) without problems with visa in the future?

And what I must do for it. Maybe buy new courses after finishing those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The student visitor route was [discontinued on 24 April 2015](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/407476/HC_1025_Immigration_Rules.pdf) and student visitor visas were "rebranded" into [Part 3 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-rules-part-3).  At that point your visa automatically converted into a "short-term student", and those visas are governed by Paragraphs A57A - A57H of the rules...

> Rebrand the student visitor, and extended student visitor routes into
>   new routes for short term study, which sit in Part 3 of the Rules, so
>   that the routes are conceptually clearer for those undertaking short
>   courses

The rule pertinent to your question is covered in [Paragraph A57D (b)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423564/20150424_immigration_rules_part_3_final.pdf)...

> intends to leave the UK at the end of the study or at the end of 6
>   months whichever is sooner.

So you need to figure out which of those two events happen sooner.  But... Because you were caught in a transition, you may wish to challenge it.  In that case you should [arrange a consultation with a solicitor](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/).

Trying to sign up for more courses is unlikely to be successful and may damage future applications.  Because you are a visa-national, it could get complex fairly quickly.